# Odd and Even Functions for equations I don't know the exponents of

Tags: functions, even-and-odd-functions

I'm solving a problem to which the final obstacle (I think) is knowing if this function is even or odd:

Given
$$xQ(x+2018)=(x-2018)Q(x)$$
and that $Q(1)=1$, what is $Q(2017)$?

My best attempt so far is plugging in $x =-1$ to which I got
$$(-1)Q(-1+2018)=(-1-2018)Q(-1)$$ 
$$Q(2017)=(2019)Q(-1)$$
I can simply conclude $Q(2017)=2019$ if I can prove $Q(-1)=Q(1)$ which brings me to the question how can I prove that $xQ(x+2018)=(x-2018)Q(x)$ is an even function? I've only been used to identifying odd and even functions for the usual polynomial/rational functions with exponents and all.

I would really appreciate the help. Thank you!

Comment: @robgimarino: As currently stated, there's not enough information. Are you sure you've stated the problem fully?

Comment: I've stated the problem exactly as reflected in the paper

Comment: What paper? A homework sheet? Can you post an image or a link?

Comment: @Robgimarino I can disprove your claim. Try to find f(-2017) which you will get 2017/4035. If f(x)=f(-x) for all x,then f(-2017)=f(2017) proving that your claim f(1)=f(-1) is wrong.

Comment: I must be looking at the problem wrongly, I see. Thanks for letting me know :) I'll  try to look at it in another way